# Can I use pipe output as a shell script argument?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, arguments

Suppose I have a bash shell script called `Myscript.sh` that need one argument as input.

But I want the content of the text file called `text.txt` to be that argument.

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
cat text.txt | ./Myscript.sh
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[Command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).

```
./Myscript.sh "$(cat text.txt)"
```

Comment: This works, but if `cat` fails, then `Myscript.sh` will still execute.
Piping with xargs ensures that the execution stops.

Answer (score 66):

You can use pipe output as a shell script argument.

Try this method:

```
cat text.txt | xargs -I {} ./Myscript.sh {}
```

Comment: Can someone please explain how this command work?

Comment: **@TalhaJunaid**, after some reading and a quick experimentation I can tell that `-I {}` (*placeholder*) splits the piped output (*reading that `text.txt` with `cat`*) - into as many arguments as there are lines in that file; so if there are 3 lines, then `Myscript.sh` will be executed 3 times: one for every line (*substituting `{}` argument placeholder*)

Answer (score 6):

To complete @bac0n which IMHO is the only one to correctly answers the question, here is a short-liner which will prepend piped arguments to your script arguments list :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -a A=("$@")
[[ -p /dev/stdin ]] && { \
    mapfile -t -O ${#A[@]} A; set -- "${A[@]}"; \
}

echo "$@"
```

Example use :

```
$ ./script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
> arg1 arg2 arg3

$ echo "piped1 piped2 piped3" | ./script.sh
> piped1 piped2 piped3

$ echo "piped1 piped2 piped3" | ./script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
> piped1 piped2 piped3 arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: `mapfile` reads **lines** from stdin as default if you want to change this behavior, e.g., if you like to split on words, you have to specify a delimiter.

Answer (score 5):

Pipe it into `xargs` before the actual command, like `cat text.txt | xargs ./Myscript.sh`

Answer (score 4):

If you have more than one set of arguments in the file (for multiple calls), consider using [xargs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) or [parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_%28software%29), e.g.

```
xargs -d '\n' Myscript.sh < text.txt
parallel -j4 Myscript.sh < text.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

By reading stdin with mapfile you can re-set the positional parameters.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

[[ -p /dev/stdin ]] && { mapfile -t; set -- "${MAPFILE[@]}"; }

for i in "$@"; do
    echo "$((++n)) $i"
done
```

```bsh
$ cat test.txt | ./script.sh
1 first
2 second line 
3 third
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
 $ cat comli.txt
 date
 who
 screen
 wget

 $ cat comli.sh
 #!/bin/bash
 which $1

 $ for i in `cat comli.txt` ; do ./comli.sh $i ; done
```

so you can enter the values one by one to `comli.sh` from `comli.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

If there are newlines (LF) or tabs in the file and you want to actually put them in one single argument (not have bash convert LF to spaces and use each word as a separate argument), you can use this:

```
./Myscript.sh "$(IFS=''; cat text.txt)"
```

(subshell used so IFS is untouched in main shell)

Simple test to show it works:

```
echo ">>>$(IFS=''; cat text.txt)<<<"
```

Non-sub-shell version:

```
IFS=" " ; echo ">>>$(cat text.txt)<<<" ; IFS=$' \t\n'
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789319/file-content-into-unix-variable-with-newlines

Answer (score 0):

This q's a bit old, but I found this solution easiest to understand and wanted to share.

If you want to accept the contents of `test.txt` as input to your script (e.g. `cat test.txt | ./myEchoScript`), you can do the following to read from stdin

```sh
if [ -p /dev/stdin ]; then
        input=$(cat)
else
        echo "expecting input to be piped in, exiting script"
        exit
fi
echo $input
```

Then to run:

```sh
$ echo "testing testing" > test.txt
$ cat test.txt | ./myEchoScript.sh 
testing testing
```